# How to use RequiredIf with a property of GUID type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, guid, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a property of string type called Address. I have a second property of GUID type called ProjectTypeId. I want to make the Address property required if ProjectTypeId equals a certain hardcoded GUID value. How can I implement this solution?

I tried the following, but compiler error CS0182 error is presented for new Guid("123-456-7890"):

```
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [TextInput(MaxLength = 10)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [RequiredIf("ProjectTypeId", new Guid("123-456-7890"), 
    ErrorMessage = "Address is required for Commercial Project Types.")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The Address must be between 1 and 10 characters.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

Note: I changed the actual GUID value in this example. The actual GUID value is something else.

Comment: `RequiredIf` attribute is the attribute built by your own? If yes, please share the `RequiredIfAttribute` class. Thanks.

Comment: public class RequiredIfAttribute : ConditionalValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override string ValidationName
        {
            get { return "requiredif"; }
        }
        public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
            : base(new RequiredAttribute(), dependentProperty, targetValue)
        {
        }
        protected override IDictionary<string, object> GetExtraValidationParameters()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object> 
        { 
            { "rule", "required" }
        };
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The following URL resource provides the solution that I needed: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dotvvm-build-conditional-validation-attribute/

I updated my code to be:

[RequiredIf("ProjectTypeId", "123-456-7890", ErrorMessage = "Address is...")]

Note: I changed the actual GUID value in this example. The actual GUID value is something else.